# What is the meaning of Text inside of AMS logo

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview

What is the meaning of the text inside this AMS logo?

[image]

The image is from [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/198603/198603FullIssue.pdf), and the logo seems to have been frequently used until the 80's. The text is

> ΑΓΕΩΜΕΤΡΗΤΟΣ ΜΗ ΕΙΣΙΤΩ

but Google translate and Googling have not helped.

> **Added: (07-11-2019)** Who is the author (designer/ suggester) of this AMS logo?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_phrases

Comment: There should be no space between (what you have written as) the first two words.

Comment: Can you show or link to this logo?  The logo at https://www.ams.org/ has no words, and I'd like to see if there are any other transcription issues (like the one in my previous comment).  It almost matches the top phrase at @damiano's link, but not quite.

Comment: This is undoubtedly a reasonably interesting question, but it is definitely not research mathematics.

Comment: Questions about (old) Greek are welcome at [Latin Language SE](https://latin.stackexchange.com/). I'm a mod there and I wouldn't mind if this was migrated there if considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

ἀγεωμέτρητος μη εἰσίτω -
*Let no one untutored in geometry enter here*

According to tradition this text was displayed in the 
entrance of Plato's Academy. (The tradition is of a late data, see this [critical discussion.](https://www.plato-dialogues.org/faq/faq009.htm)) Nicolaus Copernicus choose to print it on the cover 
page of the book *De Revolutionibus*.

[image][image]
image from [1938 (left)](http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/math-history/hmreprint-frnt.pdf) and from 
[2015 (right)](http://www.ams.org/notices/201506/201506-full-issue.pdf)

[image]
[De Revolutionibus](http://special.lib.gla.ac.uk/exhibns/month/apr2008.html)

Comment: The version of this motto in lines 18&19 on page 118 at https://archive.org/stream/inporphyriiisago00elia (which is the original, according to the Wikipedia link in @damiano's comment on the question) has μηδεὶς instead of μη.  But I guess that the meaning is the same.  (ETA: And your image agrees with Wikipedia's original.)

Comment: Can you provide a page reference in the pdf?

Comment: @MattF. --- the pages of the AMS pdf are unnumbered, the logo with the Greek text is on the 6th page.

Comment: Yes. "Que nul n'entre ici s'il n'est géomètre", in French. Someone wrote on his office at the ENS ""Que nul n'entre ici s'il n'est géomètre algébriste".

Comment: Who is the author of this AMS logo?

Comment: @C.F.G. --- there does not seem to be a record of who designed the AMS logo -- an early reference I found is from 1938 (where it was referred to as the "seal" of the society).

Comment: Its Greek spelling is so interesting for me: AGEOMETRITOS MI EISITO!!

Comment: @C.F.G Well, Aristotles would have pronounced it as it is written, "ageometretos me eisito", but let's not start the usual debeate about reuchlinian vs erasmian pronunciation of classic Greek :D

Answer (score 28):

The phrase «Μηδείς αγεωμέτρητος εισίτω μοι την θύρα» (or «Μηδείς αγεωμέτρητος εισίτω μοι την στέγη») is a phrase that supposedly was on the threshold of Plato's Academy and translates to: "do not let anyone ignorant of geometry through my door" (or under my roof). See for instance this discussion https://www.plato-dialogues.org/faq/faq009.htm

<s>The phrase in AMS' logo translates to "Do not be ignorant geometry".</s>

Edit: The above translation is not correct. The word "εισίτω" is a form of the verb "εἴσειμι" which means "to come into" ([wiktionary](https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%E1%BC%B4%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%BC%CE%B9)). I initially thought that it was a form of "ειμί" which means "to be".

So finally the AMS' logo says: "Do not enter if you don't know geometry" or "You will not enter if you don't know geometry".

Comment: Is the AMS changing the meaning by changing μηδεὶς to μη?

Comment: "μηδεὶς" translates to "no one", whereas "μη" translates to "don't". I choose to interpret AMS' phrase as "Do learn about geometry, otherwise Plato will not let you in his Academy". By the way the word "μη" is still used in modern Greek in the same way.

Comment: With the εισίτω, the AMS is still saying not to enter, right?  From "No one enter without geometry" to "Don't enter without geometry"?  (εισίτω = εἰς + ἴτω, which is imperative, right?)

Comment: (If it makes a difference, the original sources for this quotation are in Byzantine Greek, as your link attests, not Ancient Attic Greek.  I'm certainly not competent to judge any subtle differences between these.)

Comment: @TobyBartels You are absolutely right. See my edit.

Comment: For the abbreviated version in the logo, maybe the idiomatic translation would be like the signs about shirts and shoes and service:  No geometry, no entry.

Comment: @TobyBartels Indeed, the source is Elias, a commentator of Aristoteles of the 6th century, but ἀγεωμέτρητος μηδείς εἰσίτω is absolutely classic Greek. The term ἀγεωμέτρητος itself seems to be a coining of Aristoteles.